# How to declare function in another dart file and reach main variables

Tags: flutter, dart

This is part of flutter's default app.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  /*
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
  */
}
```

This is what i want to do.

```
import 'package:fdgdfg/main.dart';

class Functions {
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
}
```

I want to declare functions in another file and from this file i want to reach and use main file's variables. But i can't use these variables, i can't setstate ..
How can i do this?

Comment: You seem to have some gross misconceptions of how Classes and importing files work. I would advise you to visit https://dart.dev/ and learn a bit more about the Dart language.

Comment: that is a bad design.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have hundreds of lines of functions. My code is getting less readable. Thats why i want to put my functions in another file.

Comment: Have you attempted the answer below? If it solved your issue, please mark it as correct, and consider upvoting for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you seem to have some gross misconceptions of how `Classes` and importing files work. I would advise you to visit https://dart.dev and learn a bit more about the Dart language.

Regardless, here is an example of how you can create a `class` with `methods` on another file, import that file, instantiate the class, and use its methods on your main `class`. Beware that you cannot run `setState` on a normal Dart `class` like you were attempting. That can only be done on a `class` that extends the `StatefulWidget` Flutter class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/my_functions.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyMethods methods = MyMethods();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Say hello'),
      onPressed: () => methods.sayHello(),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**my_functions.dart**

```
class MyMethods {
  void sayHello(){
    print('Hello');
  }
}
```

You should really try to get a better understanding of how `methods`, `classes`, `context`, and `StatefulWidgets` work before moving forward with creating Flutter apps.